# Convert A Given Binary Tree To Doubly Linked List

Tags: pointers, binary-tree, pass-by-reference, doubly-linked-list, pass-by-value

The problem statement is:

> Given a Binary Tree, convert this binary tree to a Doubly Linked List.
> A Binary Tree (BT) is a data structure in which each node has at most two children.
> A Doubly Linked List contains a previous pointer, along with the next pointer and data.
> The order of nodes in Doubly Linked List must be the same as Inorder of the given Binary Tree.
> The doubly linked list should be returned by taking the next pointer as right and the previous pointer as left.
>
> You need to return the head of the Doubly Linked List.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>     4
>    / \
>   2   5
>  / \
> 1   3
> ```
>
> The doubly linked list would be: 1 2 3 4 5

My code is:

```cpp
class BinaryTreeNode 
{
public :
    T data;
    BinaryTreeNode<T> *left;
    BinaryTreeNode<T> *right;

    BinaryTreeNode(T data) {
        this -> data = data;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};

void inorder(BinaryTreeNode<int>* root,BinaryTreeNode<int>* &prev,BinaryTreeNode<int>* &nroot){
    if(!root) return;
    
    inorder(root->left,prev,nroot);
    if(prev == NULL) nroot=root;
    else{
        root->left = prev;
        prev->right=root;
    }
    prev=root;
    inorder(root->right,prev,nroot);
}

BinaryTreeNode<int>* BTtoDLL(BinaryTreeNode<int>* root) {
    BinaryTreeNode<int>* prev=NULL;
    BinaryTreeNode<int>* nroot=NULL;
    inorder(root,prev,nroot); 
    return nroot;
}
```

I have doubt regarding `root`.
The `root` pointer works with passing by value and does not works when it is passed by reference.

When root is passed by reference, it does not work.

```cpp
void inorder(BinaryTreeNode<int>*& root,BinaryTreeNode<int>*& prev,BinaryTreeNode<int>* &nroot){
    if(!root) return;
    
    inorder(root->left,prev,nroot);
    if(prev == NULL) nroot=root;
    else{
        root->left = prev;
        prev->right=root;
    }
    prev=root;
    inorder(root->right,prev,nroot);
}
```

How can I know which variable should be passed by reference and which variable should by passed by value with regard to pointers?

Comment: Look up (left) depth-first-search in your lessons. And ask your teacher that after you've done your datastructures assignments he tells you about the datastructures in STL (like std::list) since those will be the ones that you will be actually using in the future.

Comment: Please update your question so it is not a history of what first didn't work, and now works, but then another thing is still a doubt. Just from the very start of your question focus on the *current* problem. Remove the history for already is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, one problem is the API of `inorder` itself. You are assigning `nroot = root`; to see why this is a problem, consider this simpler example:

```cpp
void set_x(int *x, int *y)
{
  x = y;
}
```

Remember that pointers are really just memory addresses. So, the assignment of `x = y` says, "replace the memory address that `x` contains, and set it to whatever `y` contains". At no stage do you actually change the value *at* the memory address.

Now, considering `nroot = root` again, here you are just giving the local variable you have a new memory address, but not updating anything. So at your call side `BTtoDLL`, you provide it `nullptr` for the address, to which it never uses it, and never sets it. So, `BTtoDLL` will never see any change to `nroot`.

Comment: Hey, you mean to say that when I pass the values of prev and nroot, their values are not changed in BTtoDLL function.                                     So, I need to pass those values by reference.

Comment: I need to pass the pointers 'prev' and 'nroot' by reference. Now I have another doubt regarding 'root' pointer. The 'root' pointer works with passing by value. But when 'root' is passed by reference , it does not work. How can I know which variable should be passed by reference and which variable should by passed by value with regard to pointers?

Comment: Yes, you can take the values by reference, but I would consider an alternative API in this matter, as juggling various out-pointers can be a bit difficult to reason about. Depending on the requirements for your implementation, a better option would be to have `BinaryTreeNode<T>::traverse(std::function<void(T)>)` which will visit each node in order, and call the function on that value. With that, you could reconstruct the tree in value order in a more declarative manner.

Comment: I generally pass by `const T&` when I will be reading from the value, but it would be expensive to pass by value, and pass by `T&` when I intend to mutate the value. In your second example, since you take `root` by non-const reference, any changes you make to it will also impact the value at the call site, so you could instead take this by value, or by `const &` and make a copy of it.